# Values of matrix based on their column and row number in R

Tags: r

I have a 30 x 30 matrix in R and I want the values to be multiplied of their column and row number. For example the first value is [1] * [1] = 1

```
mat2 <- matrix(nrow= 30, ncol = 30)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `row` and `col` to get the index of row/columns and use that to multiply

```
mat2 <- row(mat2) *col(mat2)
```

Comment: I mean I want the [ row(mat2) * col(mat2) ] to be the value of each data in matrix.

Comment: @asfjnasopkd just do the assign `mat2 <-` the output is a matrix because `row` and `col` are matrix of index

Answer (score 3):

If you know the size of the matrix, you can also use `outer()` and construct the matrix directly in one step.

```r
mat2 <- outer(seq(30), seq(30))

# other simple variations:
outer(1:30, 1:30)
seq(30) %o% seq(30)
1:30 %o% 1:30
```